# error calling functions in swift with a JSON response

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

Could anyone else help me to know which is the way to call functions in swift, receiving a JSON collection response?
I'm calling ApiClient().getList() function in viewController.swift,this function calls to my API and receives a JSON response in apiClient.swift and finally I would like to assign this JSON response to self.result variable in viewController.swift.

My code is:

viewController.swift

```js
import UIKit


class ClubsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

    var results: [JSON]? = []

    @IBOutlet var tableview:UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loadClubsObjects()
    }

    func loadClubsObjects(){

        self.results = ApiClient().getList() <--- here is the call
        self.tableview.reloadData()

    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.results?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("clubsObjectCell") as! ClubsTableViewCell
        cell.clubsObject = self.results?[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

ApiClient.swift

```js
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class ApiClient {

     func getList() -> [JSON] {

            var URL = NSURL(string: "https://api.com/v1/clubs")
            var mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
            mutableURLRequest.setValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")
            mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
            mutableURLRequest.setValue("Bearer R01.iNsG3xjv/r1LDkhkGOANPv53xqUFDkPM0en5LIDxx875fBjdUZLn1jtUlKVJqVjsNwDe1Oqu2WuzjpaYbiWWhw==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
            let request = manager.request(mutableURLRequest)
            request.responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in

                if (json != nil){
                  var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                  if let data = jsonObj["hits"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                    return data

                  }
                }
            }
     }
```

and the error in apiClient.swift is

**return data** -> [JSON] is not convertible to Void

Comment: Your function returns Void. Check `func getList(completion:(data: JSON?, error: NSError?) -> Void)`

Without checking any further, this function should at least return [JSON]

Comment: Ive just update the getList() function and now I only get one error, return data -> [JSON] is not convertible to Void, how can I solve this?

Comment: replace ->Void  with -> [JSON]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getList` is defined in such a way that it's supposed to return the `[JSON]` object. But it cannot do that, because `responseJSON` is an asynchronous method (i.e. the completion closure of `responseJSON` isn't called until well after you return from `getList`).

You have to employ your own `completionHandler` pattern. For example, `getList` wouldn't return *anything,* but rather it would take a completion handler parameter:

```
func getList(completionHandler: ([JSON]) -> ()) {
    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://api.com/v1/clubs")
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)

    mutableURLRequest.setValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    mutableURLRequest.setValue("Bearer R01.iNsG3xjv/r1LDkhkGOANPv53xqUFDkPM0en5LIDxx875fBjdUZLn1jtUlKVJqVjsNwDe1Oqu2WuzjpaYbiWWhw==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
    let request = manager.request(mutableURLRequest)

    request.responseJSON { response in
        if let json = response.result.value  {
            var jsonObj = JSON(json)
            if let hits = jsonObj["hits"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                completionHandler(hits)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd invoke it like:

```
let apiClient = ApiClient()

func loadClubsObjects() {
    apiClient.getList() { hits in
        // use hits here

        self.results = hits
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // but not here
}
```

Note, I'd be inclined not to make API client a local variable of `loadClubsObjects`, but rather a class property as shown above. Do whatever you want, but it strikes me as a more logical lifecycle.

---

If you wanted to handle errors, you might change that completion handler closure such that (a) the `JSON` array of hits is optional; and (b) add an optional error object. Then change `getList` to pass back these optional values:

```
func getList(completionHandler: ([JSON]?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://api.com/v1/clubs")
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)

    mutableURLRequest.setValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    mutableURLRequest.setValue("Bearer R01.iNsG3xjv/r1LDkhkGOANPv53xqUFDkPM0en5LIDxx875fBjdUZLn1jtUlKVJqVjsNwDe1Oqu2WuzjpaYbiWWhw==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
    let request = manager.request(mutableURLRequest)

    request.responseJSON { response in
        if let json = response.result.value {
            var jsonObj = JSON(json)
            if let hits = jsonObj["hits"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                completionHandler(hits, nil)
            } else {
                let jsonError = NSError(domain: "mydomain", code: MyErrorCode.HitsNotFound, userInfo: nil) // create whatever sort of error object you think is appropriate if `hits` was not found
                completionHandler(nil, jsonError)
            }
        } else {
            completionHandler(nil, response.result.error)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you call it, you can check to see if the array of JSON objects is `nil` or not, and if it's `nil`, then look at the `NSError` object.

Comment: Thanks A lot Rob!, and which would be the best way to catch the error from the response?

Comment: Just add an additional parameter with `NSError` object to the completion handler and make sure you call the completion handler even when there is an error. My original rendition was trying to mirror your original implementation as faithfully as possible, but adding error handling like this is critical. See revised answer.